# Baby have acid reflux

Tags: food, breastfeeding, eating

My two month old have acid reflux and is on meds, but she still spit up a lot. Is that normal? I'm breastfeeding and was told breastfed babies don't spit up as much. My three year old was breastfed as well and didn't stip up at all.

Comment: Ours is five years old now, has always been on meds, and still swallows a lot in her sleep. I think most of them grow over it much faster, but I'm not sure there is a "normal" :-(

Answer (score 1):

None of my kids had reflux, but there were definitely differences in how "urpy" each one was -- since your daughter *does* have reflux, she will spit up more often.

There are some [useful suggestions in this article](http://www.breastfeedingbasics.com/articles/baby-spitting-up-is-it-reflux) and [from the Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-living/infant-and-toddler-health/in-depth/healthy-baby/art-20044329). I'd personally suggest that upright positioning during and after feedings and less milk per nursing session may be useful steps to try. My "spit uppy" child tended to keep feedings down better when I had him tied to me in a sling. So, changes like these may help reduce how much milk she's losing when she spits up.

Unfortunately, since she does have reflux, you may reach a limit of how much spit up you can prevent.

Answer (score 0):

If your baby is too full after your breastfeeding sessions, then maybe you're just letting out too much milk (believe it or not). That can be causing reflux in the baby. You should try pumping and measuring out your feedings for a bit to see if that affects her in a positive way.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the spit-up: I found it varies immensely.
 My first baby spit up a little, my second a little more. My nephew spit up A LOT, really A LOT. All breastfed. I don't know about the connection between spit up and reflux though.